# SharePoint Custom Display and edit list item forms

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm currently working on some custom forms. I have created the pages from LayoutsPageBase and they are loading up with the fields I have set.

My only issue on the edit and display forms is getting the data of the item that the user has requested to edit or display.

How do you get the data of the item?

Thanks

Truez

Comment: `My only issue on the edit and display forms is getting the data of the item that the user has requested to edit or display.` isn't this the expected behavior (show data of the item you open) ???

Answer (score 0):

Go on just like what SharePoint does in order to show item data. Both display forms and edit forms start by reading the query string value "ID":

```
string strItemId = Request.QueryString["ID"];
```

You can add some validations to check if the query parameter exists and if it is actually a number and if an item actually exists in that list with the given ID. Finally, store valid itemId in an integer variable and retrieve the item as follows:

```
SPListItem item = myList.GetItemByID(itemId);
```

Continue to fill in the controls (labels in case of display forms and text boxes, drop downs, ... in case of edit forms) with item fields as below:

```
txtTitle.Text = item["Title"] + String.Empty;
```

You will then need to set item fields for the edit form on save button click event and then update the item.

Comment: Thats very helpful but i have found another way will post shortly thanks :)